# Heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones already tried different tutorials

Tags: rigging, rigify

I cant parent my rig with automatic weights to my model blend file attached in the google drive page:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/133a4L3RS1Y7VVYdKtPc1pMDmDedBrKFb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your model has no duplicate vertices and no intersecting mesh segments?  Also, stack exchange prefers that you use blend-exchange to add your file to your question: [How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)

Comment: Nope those aren't your problems, Blender just can't handle a model with nearly 3 million vertices

Comment: @MartyFouts Do you think you could help? I tried decimate and brought the count to 500k but it still doesn't work. can you try parenting it for me?

Comment: Unfortunately, the best way to solve your problem is to re-topologize the model, trying to preserve as much form as possible while producing a smaller mesh.  It's not something I'm any good at. Sorry.

Comment: it looks super high in polygons (almost 3 millions faces), why don't you use a low-poly version? just bake the normals of this version to keep all the 3D details...

Comment: @moonboots I have no idea how to do that... Are there any good tutorials on it?

Comment: it is called retopology, you'll easily find tutorials, you need to create a new object and enable the Snap option in order to stick your low-poly to the high-poly

Comment: @moonboots OMG OMG OMG I tried decimate wayyy low and I actually got it, thanks for telling me about the high face count

Comment: if Decimate doesn't alterate your shape, use it, then retopologize, because Decimate won't give you a good topology